# Can a service be started by normal user on Windows?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, windows-services

I have a service application created with Delphi, and managed to install it from another Delphi application using elevated privileges.

The service is set to log on as the Local System account (which is default when creating a service application in Delphi).

I have another Delphi application in which an ordinary user is supposed to be able to start or stop the above service.

My question is: Is this allowed by Windows? When I try to start the service using code in Delphi, it just fails with 'Code 5. Access is denied.' How can I prevent this error from occurring? I want to be able to have the normal user running the application (not in Administrator mode and thus not with elevated privileges) to start / stop the service. Is it possible and if so how? Below is my code:

```
function ServiceStart(sMachine, sService: string): boolean;
var
  schm, schs: SC_Handle;
  ss: TServiceStatus;
  psTemp: PChar;
  dwChkP: DWord; // check point
begin
  ss.dwCurrentState := 0;
  // connect to the service control manager
  schm := OpenSCManager(PChar(sMachine), nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  // if successful...
  if (schm <> 0) then
  begin
    // open a handle to the specified service
    // we want to start the service and query service
    // status
    schs := OpenService(schm, PChar(sService), SERVICE_START  or SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
    // if successful...
    if (schs <> 0) then
    begin
      psTemp := nil;
      if (StartService(schs, 0, psTemp)) then
      begin
        // check status
        if (QueryServiceStatus(schs, ss)) then
        begin
          while (SERVICE_RUNNING <> ss.dwCurrentState) do
          begin
            // dwCheckPoint contains a value that the
            // service increments periodically to
            // report its progress during a
            // lengthy operation. Save current value
            dwChkP := ss.dwCheckPoint;
            // wait a bit before checking status again
            // dwWaitHint is the estimated amount of
            // time the calling program should wait
            // before calling QueryServiceStatus()
            // again. Idle events should be
            // handled here...
            Sleep(ss.dwWaitHint);
            if not QueryServiceStatus(schs, ss) then
            begin
              // couldn't check status break from the
              // loop
              break;
            end;

            if ss.dwCheckPoint < dwChkP then
            begin
              // QueryServiceStatus didn't increment
              // dwCheckPoint as it should have.
              // Avoid an infinite loop by breaking
              break;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin

        if MessageDlg('Start Service failed. Do you want remove it?',
          mtWarning, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrYes then
        begin
          InstallUninstallService(1);
        end;

      end;

      // close service handle
      CloseServiceHandle(schs);
    end else RaiseLastOSError;
    // close service control manager handle
    CloseServiceHandle(schm);
  end;
  // Return TRUE if the service status is running
  Result := SERVICE_RUNNING = ss.dwCurrentState;
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default you need to have admin privileges to start, stop, install and delete services.

You will have to arrange for your service to expose its own Active property, distinct from what Windows terms as running. Arrange that it is running in Windows terms all the time, but inert when its Active property is false.

You'll have to implement a control mechanism for your user app. I've done this with named pipes but the are other IPC methods available.

Comment: The user that is running the application has Administrator privilege on Windows 7, yet the function call to start the service fails. It only works if the application was started with 'Run as Administrator'. Why is this?

Comment: Because it needs elevation. You should properly tell the user, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511445.aspx, and then perform the elavation.

Comment: Ok understood. Thanks. Can you just confirm one last thing? When I run the Services Control panel from Run dialog with services.msc  or  when I right click My Computer and click on Manage - does it run elevated even though it does not give a prompt?

Comment: My Computer -> Manage shows the elevation shield, the whole Computer Management console is run elevated. "Services" doesn't display the shield, but I guess that's a MS mistake, it should. In Windows 7 not every elevation requires a confirmation (in Vista it does, and it's a nightmare :)

Comment: @idsandon ha, I always dial up the UAC settings so that I know exactly which operations need elevation

Comment: @steve I actually recommend that you dial up UAC to its maximum setting. It will help you be more familiar of which actions require elevation.

Answer (score 3):

Services hava ACLs as other Windows objects. In a domain permissions to start/stop services may be assigned to users using group policies (under Computer Configuration -> Polices -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> System Services). AFAIK this node does not appear in gpedit.msc for a local system. sc.exe could be used to set a service security descriptor, but it requires some knowledge of SDDL (Security Descriptor Definition Language, [this may help you](http://msmvps.com/blogs/erikr/archive/2007/09/26/set-permissions-on-a-specific-service-windows.aspx)). Don't know if a template is available to allow gpedit to handle that - it's a bit uncommon a standalone system for which the user has no admin account.

Comment: Yes. See the link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve this:

### 1. Give permissions to the service

This must be done in elevated mode, for example when creating the service.

Beware that Windows [access control model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374876(v=vs.85).aspx) is hard to work with. Maybe [JEDI Windows Security Library](http://jwscldoc.delphi-jedi.net/) can help you.

Permissions can be granted to individual users, to user groups or to predefined user groups, such as authenticated users.

To do this you need to create an [access control list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the service. Services hace several [access rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685981(v=VS.85).aspx#access_rights_for_a_service), and for this purpose you need to include **SERVICE_START** and **SERVICE_STOP** in the acl.

The acl is applied using [SetSecurityDescriptorDacl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379583(v=VS.85).aspx) and [SetServiceObjectSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379589(v=VS.85).aspx) api functions. Here is an example in C of [how to use them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684215(v=VS.85).aspx).

The user or group must be specified filling the [Trustee](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379636(v=VS.85).aspx) variable of the [EXPLICIT_ACCESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446627(v=vs.85).aspx) structure with the desired [SID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721625(v=VS.85).aspx#_security_security_identifier_gly). Here is another example in C showing [how to do it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446595(v=vs.85).aspx).

*Note:* Microsoft has an utility called [SubInACL](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23510) that can be used to query and set all kind of acls, though I guess it is not redistributable. Here is a mini-tutorial on [how to use it](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/subinacl.php).

### 2. Use a guardian service

You can have another service that respond to commands and controls the main service. This guardian should be running as **LocalSystem**. LocalSystem has **SERVICE_START** and **SERVICE_STOP** privileges, so it's no needed to set any acl for the guardian.

The guardian also allows you to autoupdate the main service, by simply stopping, updating and restarting it.

Beware that LocalSystem is some kind of local administrator, so it is a security risk to use it, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449946/what-are-the-security-risks-in-running-a-windows-service-as-local-system/1452089#1452089).

### 3. Implement activate/deactive commands in the service

As [David Heffernan says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172942/can-a-service-be-started-by-normal-user-on-windows/7172965#7172965), it is no needed to start and stop the service, as similar behavior can be achieved by exposing commands that instructs it to internally deactivate and activate independently of what windows thinks.

Comment: You don't need a Guardian service. You can send the commands direct to the real service and get it to behave accordingly without actually starting and stopping. And isn't it bad practice to use LocalSystem?

Comment: @David: The OP explicitly asked for start and stop the service, so I answer to that, though as you say a similar behavior can be obtained with commands to the real service, except if you want to update the service exe. LocalSystem is some kind of local administrator, so you are right in that it can be risky to use it.

Comment: I actually think your answer is the most comprehensive, my comment was just meant to add a couple of hopefully useful angles

Comment: @David: Thanks. I am sorry that I can't post code implementing alternative #1. I've coded it in the past, but I have not access to it and is rather complex to write.

Comment: What is this answer? A summary of previous ones??

Comment: @ldsandon: No. Alternatives #1 and #2 are mine. Later I add #3 to include David's one.

Comment: #1 was alread answered by mad hatter. You added what API to call, but if a user can't start a service can't set its permissions also, usually. Only #2 is yours.

Comment: @ldsandon: Mad Hater's answer involves using windows utilities, my #1 explain how to change permissions programatically, which is a different beast. I clearly state that "This must be done in elevated mode, for example when creating the service", so it can really be done.

Comment: @ldsandon it's fine to write an answer that encompasses other answers if it is a better answer, as I believe this to be.

Comment: The problem is if you can't start the service you can't also set its privileges from code because you have no rights. It should be performed by someone else with enough rights. That's why I suggested Windows utilities - because a system administrator usually doesn't call APIs, at least I never found one who could. They could write scripts though, and set policies.

Comment: @Mad: If you can create the service then you can also change it's privileges. I clearly state that "This must be done in elevated mode, for example when creating the service". Besides that, SO is a site about programming, and programs call APIs, so I think that if there is a programmatic way of solve this problem it's well worth mentioning it here. Of course, your answer is also fine.