# What is the disadvantage of having Local system set in app pool instead of Network service?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

What is the disadvantage of having Local System set in app pool instead of Network Service in IIS7 of Windows server 2008?

Comment: why there should be any disadvantage? Can you explain what are you experiencing or give some more context?

Answer (score 3):

Local system is a more priviledged account than the Network service and should be avoided if possible.

See the [Services and Service Accounts Security Planning Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc170953) for further information on how to configure the application accounts from a security perspective.

Also see these related questions on the security aspects:

- [What are the security risks in running a Windows Service as “Local
  System”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449946/what-are-the-security-risks-in-running-a-windows-service-as-local-system)
- [Why running a service as Local System is bad on
  windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730486/why-running-a-service-as-local-system-is-bad-on-windows)
- [The difference between the 'Local System' account and the 'Network Service' account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510170/the-difference-between-the-local-system-account-and-the-network-service-acco)